# Spring Boot: how to customize JSON response in case of error (using ControllerAdvice)

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, exception, httpresponse

Using Spring Boot Rest API: I have an end point that I use for login of user. When the user's credentials are not valid an UnauthorizedException is thrown, with a custom message.

By using a custom Exception and a ErrorDetails object, I have set the error message response accordingly.

However I keep getting a JSON response back from Spring Boot containing an extensive header. How can I customize the header that it only returns what I want to see?

This is the JSON message that I get back as a response. I however would prefer to only get the error: {} part of it back.

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 401,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/access/login",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/access/login: 401 OK",
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid username and/or password.",
    "details": "uri=/access/login",
    "timestamp": "2019-03-29T14:52:28.863+0000"
  }
}
```

This is the code used for the ControllerAdvice, ErrorDetails and UnauthorizedException:

```
public class ErrorDetails {
    private String message;
    private String details;
    private Date timestamp;

    public ErrorDetails(String message, String details, Date timestamp) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> unauthorizedException(UnauthorizedException e, WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(e.getMessage(), webRequest.getDescription(false),new Date());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> globalExceptionHandler(Exception e, WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(e.getMessage(), webRequest.getDescription(false),new Date());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}



@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UnauthorizedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that for me is working properly:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(value = IllegalArgumentException.class)
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidBody(IllegalArgumentException ex, WebRequest request) {
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "Error message", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
        }
    }
```

When you throw an `IllegalArgumentException` is gonna be handled by that.